# Apache: redirect URL of internal WSGI server

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2

The following Apache `conf` file serves a WSGI application via port 9002:

```
<VirtualHost *:9002>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    WSGIDaemonProcess matching-server user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/matching-server/server.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/matching-server>
        WSGIProcessGroup matching-server
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The WSGI server responds to `/metadata` call, and returns a JSON with uptime information. I would like to alias `/api` to `/metadata`, so that calls to `/api` will be re-written as calls to `/metadata` and sent to the internal WSGI server.

I have enabled `mod_rewrite` on the Ubuntu server:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And added the following rewrite rule to the `conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^api/?$    /metadata    [NC,L]
```

I tried adding the rewrite rule after the `SSL` section and inside the `Directory` section, but I am still getting a `Not Found` error when accessing `/api`:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Needless to mention, `/metadata` works without problems with or without the redirect rule.

Any idea what's wrong with my rewrite rule?

Comment: your rewrite rule should not be in your conf file, it should be in your htaccess file. Also if you have changed your apache.conf file restart apache after you have removed the rewrite and saved your file

Comment: Are you sure? I tried placing it in the `.htaccess` file and got an `Internal Server Error` response. The error log output is `.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here`.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789692/where-do-i-put-rewriterules-in-apache2-without-using-htaccess-files are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: Ah wait sorry try this http://docs.silvacms.org/2.3/wsgi.html sorry i didn't see that it was WSGI

Comment: even in 2014 why would you use .htaccess files for rewrites to application servers URIs like wsgi where all of the paths are virtual and have no meaningful mapping to the local filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed a `PT` flag instead of `[NC, L]` in order to pass the result URL to `WSGIScriptAlias`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/api$   /metadata    [PT]
```

Quoting [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#page-header):

> The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be
>   a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be
>   treated as a URI instead. That is to say, the use of the [PT] flag
>   causes the result of the RewriteRule to be passed back through URL
>   mapping, so that location-based mappings, such as Alias, Redirect, or
>   ScriptAlias, for example, might have a chance to take effect.